# How to fix 'This token is not signed' while using Laravel access_token

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I want to build Laravel rest api with Laravel Passport token. 
I generate access_token with my client secret key and I got the access token, but when I want to access the api with the access token always get message `"exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'This token is not signed' in /vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Token.php:194"`.
how to solve this error?

I've tried to generate new key, clear cache with `php artisan cache:clear` but not worked

This is my code to generate token
1. Generate access token with client secret key

Url : `https://xxxxx/oauth/token`

Parameter

```
{
    "grant_type":"client_credentials",
    "client_id":"41",
    "scope":"*",
    "client_secret":"CFprIY1qWznahoKDMomTAqLUx6IALfWR0xLwKjwA"
}
```

Response

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 300,
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjIxYTg4NzQ2YmE1N2U5OGE3NDZlZDg5MmUyYjU3ZmZkOGFkNjJlYWZiMWNjMzk0MDU2NGQ1N2ZjZjE2MDcwYzFjMjYwYTE1MGU1N2MzYzQyIn0.eyJhdWQiOiI0MSIsImp0aSI6IjIxYTg4NzQ2YmE1N2U5OGE3NDZlZDg5MmUyYjU3ZmZkOGFkNjJlYWZiMWNjMzk0MDU2NGQ1N2ZjZjE2MDcwYzFjMjYwYTE1MGU1N2MzYzQyIiwiaWF0IjoxNTU3NzMzMzc2LCJuYmYiOjE1NTc3MzMzNzYsImV4cCI6MTU1NzczMzY3Niwic3ViIjoiIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.GGKOd-WRBT-UNmdDJe2WdUmatrumbwlDLlP0f1LKrAikU3JhwG8xkD4iLDUwmcaT5S37-GUSrdWjI3nnzNkAyFexLLJH7Vr6n7QsskWLH80ZR5mTaFXLgmsprp15UeoXm3op52Pa-Hq2mqx3C_nxQNxLElF68obApVhuYDLd2u46YP0b_DoYJqqg85sLGHyUsC95ofkMytmMc_aVoiOS1UmAoSn597p5ovJ3F47MakyuezduBvFWlA4wKxsW1wHjRe_4AkldzGhif16p_lbdBNg2HR-zQXYkmMHBjqLUd17R3w7fyOi5C_Z02gEkH78KqPP2KcbdJWhneLM_MpzkdYpTZVAI-F3NmCG1IehTa9MkSpbMMfLw0MZwsoCEv6mh20R6gZE6TnvZ3emcFstbgrjxIdbSOWaohqUPtSobrDDI-wsP9RqSgRJP3EWqQKnXG_Qbz8C6J3IZxcYERnSumVdoerpHNF5ZdtgqO4kGeROZ49mc3osr3ZkY0jwS40zNIoiNTlH1GqDuYReFZ12ua07DqAxRkRLmmKPscIO8Gwe06VBYuBcrPCNnwsvzNLfCeFNlN0Hnw6eYuSQKriua7g_e1EyZKwlrF4d52NtcSe455EuaeM1XzFirCGywabtV6PhaK-lk8E7Ot-ULfiUiMkvJy2TmhLvGhE4scYTkLVQ"
}
```

2. Access the API

Url : `https://xxxxx/api/loginApi`

```
Header : Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImZhZGZjZTRlZjA0NDdlNzliNmY1MjlkNzRjZjY3MTlkMWNjNDY1ZGMwNjE2MmY1NzM2YWZlNjcwMjNkNTkxMmVkNjA2OTJlZTIxNmRjMmRlIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIyIiwianRpIjoiZmFkZmNlNGVmMDQ0N2U3OWI2ZjUyOWQ3NGNmNjcxOWQxY2M0NjVkYzA2MTYyZjU3MzZhZmU2NzAyM2Q1OTEyZWQ2MDY5MmVlMjE2ZGMyZGUiLCJpYXQiOjE1NTc3MzM0MzcsIm5iZiI6MTU1NzczMzQzNywiZXhwIjoxNTg5MzU1ODM3LCJzdWIiOiIzODMiLCJzY29wZXMiOltdfQ.wYdEtWtawtZvhW4aG-O1Jb0YkoOyD_p_iNOLJg0AT9zoTBzVrOAioj_0SbRWc1DfbR4Srxnsjc13Z1G_G2803ekWrO72WYvQN21NGasXbH8FtRUaXFoE5qh-Pv2jtuwj3SeEcezmhOiqNKnSxo-9FvcNMTirDILZmSxOaVShQMv7St683nkPthH2b14afqfJb2QowJDHIzoMryt92OGCis6DtjxDb8Au7y0XotJwTU8IyZHumH3EF-hu8Yn3o0VEQbeOBVsjpqGKc_VYYeAdp9FbEg804TVPaVlfVbHRripqPKXOv8JmkE4vxGBS-abtrBQmRfU-jNgmTvkcVHSAWyycLKY8NiRUmWwFHly-IfviWxDnOEOYVDzY5ZaP0TGapZRpQEVBW12QauGtlxZ76NOxb9RZVX_dTgfXvS22icGW0XJPPM8eobYeyzwZvpBovBnCxJxKp_EgJZPeTG1bBzwderp1b3OXNc2gF_U2iUAxAIMohKKAe0JFzNe0bmsueQOLul8jc9ZjxP2Km2a5OHxnvTK_5dBWFN62yuGkJb8JJz5U5beUTbIaPPmJqu7n8rqyz3E5IGmxQUH0XES_ZMayMrvwI03PLQVmtngCb2MeOZjxRll3GtJGlpXYhoTPCeyQz7m-VWaCkNgfohEtt-1W7tGU8X_sMwNwyKRhzjM
```

```
[{"key":"Accept","value":"application/json","description":"","type":"text","enabled":true}]
```

Result :
`development.ERROR: exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'This token is not signed' in /xxxxxxvendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Token.php:194`

Answer (score 0):

I think you've missed the traits `HasApiTokens` in User.php

Please add the traits like below

```
use HasApiTokens,Notifiable;
```

Comment: I've added HasApiTokens,Notifiable in my user model before.

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable,HasApiTokens;

 protected $table    = 'users';
   
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}